# Dynamically chaining methods in TypeScript (bumping version number of message)

Tags: typescript

I'm re-writing our company's analytics pipeline. Our pipeline currently receives messages in a format similar to:

```
{
    version: 6, // <--- The important bit
    timeOnPage: 100,
    clicks: 4,
    ...
}
```

Our old system had a massive switch statement and different classes to handle each message version. So if an older client sent a version 2 message it would load up the version 2 message handler. If a newer client send a version 5 message, we load up the version 5 message handler.

With the re-write I'm trying to make our code more maintainable and easier to trace errors. As part of this, I've decided that we should convert all messages to the latest version upon arrival before further processing -- that way we only have to write our processing logic once and errors can only live in one place.

To avoid having to ***re-write*** all of our message conversion scripts if a new version is released (e.g. updating our `v1 -> v6` function to make it a `v1 -> v7` function) I decided to implement a simple "version bumping pipeline". When a message arrives if the version number doesn't match the latest version, we run the function to bump it by 1, then repeat. So a v1 message will first be converted to a v2 message, then be converted to a v3 message, then be converted to a v4 message, etc.

I've written most of the code to do this. In TypeScript, it looks like so:

```
/// v1.ts -- just a type definition and a no-op function
export type MessageV1 = {
    version: 1,
    ...
};
export function convert(msg: MessageV1): MessageV1 {
    return msg;
}



/// v2.ts -- defines the v2 message spec and provides a function for converting v1 messages
export type MessageV2 = {
    version: 2,
    ...
};
export function convert(msg: MessageV1): MessageV2 {
    const v2 = (msg as any) as MessageV2;
    // ... converting logic ...
    return v2;
}



/// v3.ts -- defines the v3 message spec and provides a function for converting v2 messages
export type MessageV3 = {
    version: 3,
    ...
};
export function convert(msg: MessageV2): MessageV3 {
    const v3 = (msg as any) as MessageV3;
    // ... converting logic ...
    return v3;
}



/// convert.ts -- our "version bumping pipeline"
import {convert as v1, MessageV1} from "./v1";
import {convert as v2, MessageV2} from "./v2";
import {convert as v3, MessageV3} from "./v3";

const converters = [v1, v2, v3];

type Message = MessageV1 | MessageV2 | MessageV3;

export function convert(msg: Message): MessageV3 {
    while (msg.version < 3) {
        const func = converters[msg.version];
        msg = func(msg);
    }
}
```

I'm not **super** happy with how the function is written (I have to manually update the file if a new version is added to add an import, append it to the array of converters, update the version-less "Message" type definition, ***and*** increment the while-loop conditional) but I figured I can work on improvements after the basic system is working.

My problem is that TypeScript doesn't like this method of iteratively calling unknown "convert" functions. As you can see here, when I first declare "func" it has an appropriate type:

```
((input: MessageV1) => MessageV1) | ((input: MessageV1) => MessageV2) | ((input: MessageV2) => MessageV3)
```

[image]

However ***one line later*** it has forgotten this type and now thinks it's a:

```
(input: never) => Message
```

[image]

Is there a proper way to do what I'm trying to do? Am I approaching this from the entirely wrong angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *call* a function that has a union of function types, typescript performs an intersection on all arguments, and the return value. This makes sense because you need an argument that is valid to be passed to any of the functions in the union.

So when you call this type:

```
((input: MessageV1) => MessageV1) | ((input: MessageV1) => MessageV2) | ((input: MessageV2) => MessageV3)
```

Typescript requires an argument of type:

```
MessageV1 & MessageV1 & MessageV2
```

Which would clearly result in `never` since the `version` constant cannot be `1 & 1 & 2`.

It's hard to recommend a specific solution without a minimal reproducible example, but this should at least point you toward the problem.

---

Though I do think doing this in a loop might be a bit hard for typescript to keep track of. What about something like this?

```
function modernize(message: Message): MessageV3 {
  if (message.version === 1) message = convert1to2(message)
  if (message.version === 2) message = convert2to3(message)
  return message
}

const messageV3 = modernize({ version: 1, data1: 'some data' })
console.log(messageV3.data3) // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQgEDcEYDoBcGdQFomgFYFd61AQ1LAJ4AOApqACakBmAlgHa2y0D29e9Feo9LSLxUNQz0AxszYAoUgA9iLAE44iZUAFlS8eLgDmpAGqRQAXlABvSaCsRSC+K3oAuUJAA0l6xVyxckZ9gUGHXcAXwBuaTlFHGExCXZRNnBbWEhYFkgACgBbeB1nDS1dA0gASgLNbT1Dcw8rBVJYDAV2XJ0IkMkuyRBgCAAmOEQUShoGTQIAC3JwftBsyuLQeDJRDi5iBRZwWipEfFjxByFFUET6ZKUgiCMFor14SPklAhJyQqqDOdMLaxs7BzOfruP5eHz9fywQL0YKScJPaJCERHNhnJIpNIsfo5PIVe4lcrqRbVOa-aznbADEygHE6PD7eiEUr0on4-T9CJ-MDQHloi4pa4AGxYOloax50DqoAaTRaAw63R6YHAAGYhshUFQ6PQJrBphAVfNieQVqQ1rhOKBNttdhMDsj4icFHzLswYVS7p9HrJnso3qzPvpDT8pZd7GxnCqQZ5vLgVZDobD4T7EYdHedXf10iraXjA-1CR9ikHan8KThVdTaSyLUyWUXqirOdZubyMwL3cLReKeVKZc12KqFZIVO9jdSGyVQAAfAPFuazydBrpp47ZFhUFq0ABepByxrzxULxpLZNo1BpnuK0DDx2M95czKvemp7aUmOxz9IpQ858vxpvWxw3Ye9TALI18VfdElCzFgcy-H96kaAcIM+OEunLVDi2DeYN1sRhd0yMx-mA5w3EoWM-FAAByeAWAWCifGo0AQh-CkWEFUhoC7fc2TVME42ZMAAHdFAAa3gIA)

Comment: The if waterfall worked perfectly. No more loop, TypeScript is happy, and it even inferred that the final type was a v3 message without me having to explicitly cast!